# Getting the index of a random array and then using the same index to print another array

Tags: java, arrays, indexing

I've been trying to use for loops for this problem about 3 1/2 hours already knowing full well they probably wont work but could not think of a better way.

Basically: A random number is generated with this:

```
public static int[] toll = {100, 150, 200, 350, 900};
public static int[] tollId = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

public static int randomToll() {
    int random = new Random().nextInt(toll.length);
    thisObject = toll[random];
    return thisObject;
}

public static void print() {
    System.out.println(tollId[*ThisIndexEqualToRandomIndexFromToll*]);
}
```

And now I want to get the index of the random number in the array or "thisObject" rather, then I want that index to be set to the same index of the tollId that gets printed, hopefully that makes sense. I really just cannot think of how to write it and if there is a better way then using arrays, please let me know.

Comment: I Should have clarified: In essence if 100 gets picked as a random number, i'd like for tollId[0] to get printed and so on. I know I can just add if/else statements but there has to a better way to do it.

Comment: **Why** not take a random index from `toll` directly? What is the ***point*** of `tollId`?

Comment: That's just how i need it to be, like I said, if there is a better way than using arrays, please let me know.

Comment: You need to clarify why, taking a random index from `toll` is essentially what you're doing (but you have an off by one issue) and you're creating an entire array for no reason I can discern.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is after getting the random index for toll I want that same index to be applied to tollId, in the one i'm working on the tollid is the object so it gets spawned and when it gets picked i want it to take from the toll so if the toll random index that was selected is toll[2] it should take the tollId[2]

Comment: Valid indexes in `toll` are `0`, `1`, `2`, `3` and `4`. There still seems to be no valid purpose to assigning random indexes in `tollId` (which is an *object*, it's an array of primitive `int`s).

Comment: The value of `tollId` is simply the value of the random index + 1. Or, if you truly need these bound together, do not use two arrays, but create an class that keeps the values together, put the instantiations of that class into an array, and randomly pick one. Maintaining two arrays here, given the example data, makes no sense.

Comment: I need them to be like this the numbers arent actually 1 2 3 4 5 its high numbers

Answer (score 0):

I would invert the logic slightly. Get the index, and then you can retrieve the toll at a future point. There is no need to track two arrays when the 2nd array is just a number (well, the index + 1, but that can be added in an output).

```
public static int[] toll = { 100, 150, 200, 350, 900 };

// get the location for the random toll
public static int randomTollId() {
  // will return an index between 0 and the # of tolls
  return new Random().nextInt(toll.length);
}

public static void print()
{
   int idx = randomTollId();
   System.out.println("The index of " + idx + " has a toll of " + toll[idx]);
}
```